# Cakephp: How to keep form filled when going temporarily to another form?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

in cakephp 2.3:

Suppose I have a form generated by `controllerX`. I start filling in data, and somewhere there is a button for performing some task which will open a new form (modal window) generated by `controllerY` for `ModelY`.
Whenever I am finishing with the second form I am losing all what I have filled in the 1st form.
I tried several things, including redirecting to `$this->referrer()`, but all not working.

Thanks

**Update 1)**
I am adding a snippet of the code:
Note: I am using twitter bootstrap. Below code is from "violations" add view. Inside this form, I want to enable the user to add a new Organization.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        /****** helper functions *******/
    function onClickAddOrgLink() {
        $('#myModal').modal();
    }

</script>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('number');
echo $this->Form->input('organization_id');
//Add new organization button
echo '<a id="addOrgLink" href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Add new Org</a>';
$this->Js->get('#addOrgLink')->event('click', 'onClickAddOrgLink()');

echo $this->Form->input('remarks', array('type'=>'textarea','rows'=>'6'));
echo $this->Form->end(array('class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'div'=>false,'name'=>'submit', 'label' => 'add'));
?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">adding a new org</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Organization', array('controller'=>'organizations', 'action'=>'add'));
            echo $this->Form->input('company_name', array('div'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->input('address1', array('div'=>false));

            echo '  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            echo $this->Form->end(array('class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'div'=>false, 'name'=>'submit', 'label' => 'ADD'));
            echo '</div>';
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is add new organization action:

```
var $helpers=array('Session', 'Js', 'Html');

    public function add() {
        $this->autoRender=false;
        $this->Organization->create();
        $this->Organization->save($this->request->data);
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a 'full' answer, but some suggestions that may assist in implementing a solution;

### option 1 - Autosave (draft)

Implement `autosave`; on any page containing a form, add a JavaScript that submits the form (via AJAX) to a server-side autosave handler at a specific interval (e.g. Every xx seconds) *or* when the user navigates away for the page.

The server-side handler stores the submitted data inside the session, using the URL of the page as 'identifier' (e.g. /Users/edit/123). When returning to the page, check if a draft(autosave) is present in the session, and use that information to fill the request data;

```
public function beforeRender() {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        // restore autosave data for the current url if no form is posted
        $this->request->data = $this->AutosaveComponent->restore($this->request->here);
    } else {
        // form is posted; flush the autosave data for the current URL
        $this->AutosaveComponent->flush($this->request->here);
    }
}
```

### Option 2 - light box

Another option is to open the 'interrupting' form in a light box; the form that is currently worked on will stay open, and submitting the light box form will not interrupt this.

### update - some suggestions

Basically, what you're trying to achieve is;

- the user picks an organisation, enters the remarks and submits the form
- if the organization does not yet exist, allow the user to *add* a new organization via a modal/popup. Select that organization after adding it via the Modal, enter the remarks and complete the form.

#### Use AJAX to submit the Modal box

Currently, your Modal-windows will be submitted via a 'regular' submit, not via AJAX, therefore the page will be reloaded after submitting the modal box.

You should submit the Modal box via AJAX and afterwards, append the newly created organization to the dropdown using a AJAX 'complete' handler.

However, because you'll also have to show validation-errors for *the organization* inside the Modal box, it may be better to *load* the 'add organization form' via AJAX as well.

All these will require quite some changes to your code *and* additional JavaScript to perform the AJAX handling.

#### Create the new Organization *and* submit the remark at the same time

Basically, combine both forms into a single form;

- By default, the input-fields for the 'Organization' are hidden
- If the user picks an existing organization from the dropdown, the 'Organization' fields remain hidden
- If the user picks 'other organization...' from the dropdown, the 'Organization' fields become visible and the user can enter the details for the new organization

After submitting the form:

- if the user selected 'other organization...', insert the new organization and insert the 'remark', using the 'id' of the new organization.
- if the user selected an *existing* organization, only insert the remark.

Comment: I have mentioned already that I am using a modal window (i.e. pop-up). However, this is also not working

Comment: But you're *redirecting* the *first/original page* afterwards? Why?

Comment: I have updated the original post. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Thank you, I think it's clear what you're trying to achieve. Don't think I'll be able to provide a complete solution within the context of StackOverflow, but I'll try to add some 'pointers' to my answer.

Comment: I hope you'll be able to achieve what you want. Good luck!